# QTableView Expansion

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableView and I wish to allow the table expansion just for the second column. The problem is the last column is also expanding.

```
  ui   -> tableview -> setModel(m_Model);       

  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colNo, 30);
  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colName, 30);
  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colN, 30);
  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colFx, 30);
  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colFy, 30);
  ui   -> tableview ->setColumnWidth(CModel::colFxy, 30);

  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colNo,       QHeaderView::Fixed);
  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colName,     QHeaderView::Stretch);
  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colN,        QHeaderView::Fixed);
  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colFx,       QHeaderView::Fixed);
  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colFy,       QHeaderView::Fixed);
  ui   -> tableview -> header() -> setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colFxy,      QHeaderView::Fixed);
```

This is resizing both de second and the last column:
[image]

Any opinions?

Comment: have you tried to add `tableview->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);` ?

Comment: Yes. Nothing change.

Comment: I have a similar setup and it works fine for me. Are you sure your enum/column for fxy is correct?

Comment: Yes. I use the same structure to fill the rows with data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you code compiles, but I think shuld be

```
ui->tableview->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(CModel::colNo, QHeaderView::Fixed);
...
```